# Laravel cannot use custom App PHP files in controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autoload

In my controller I am trying to use a PHP file that is located within the App directory.

My controller looks like

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\MyClass\API;
    public function getservices(Request $request)
    {
        $sourcename = request('sName');
        $password = request('password');
        $siteID = request('siteID');

       // initialize default credentials
        $creds = new SourceCredentials($sourcename, $password, 
        array($siteID));
```

The SourceCredentials Class is within the API.PHP file, located in App\MyClass\API, this is API.PHP

```
namespace App\MyClass;

class SourceCredentials
{
    public $SourceName;
    public $Password;
    public $SiteIDs;
    //some other stuffs
```

When I make a POST request to the controller using my routes, I get this error -

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SourceCredentials' not found

Am I making some mistakes here? I have named the namespace correctly for the API.PHP and I am using that namespace in my controller. Please help.

Comment: _Note:_ `SourceCredentials` is a class, not a function.

Comment: Yes, but my API.PHP file has more than one classes, and SourceCredentials is one of them

Comment: Break that file up and save each class in it's own file with the same name as the class (including the same casing). Then make sure you have the correct namespaces in your files and you will be able to load the classes you want with Laravels auto loader.

Comment: Thank you. I did that, it works but I have another problem. I cannot use the function related to that class. I am already extending the controller class, and I cannot extend another class to use that function

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you have a new (different) issue, please create a new question with all the information and examples.

Comment: I just want to use a function in API.PHP file.

Comment: If it contains actual _functions_ and not classes, then you need to include the file using `require`/`include` or similar.

Comment: In that case i recommend that put that function in some file called `helpers.php` or something like that and require through composer autoloader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use is :

```
use App\MyClass\API;
```

while your class name is :

```
SourceCredentials
```

Correct your use like so :

```
use App\MyClass\SourceCredentials;
// or if you want to youse the API name
use App\MyClass\SourceCredentials as API;
```

Comment: Thank you. But my API.php file has multiple classes, like UserCredentials, API Service and so on. What is the best way to use all the classes?

Comment: Which psr are you following ? And I don't think it's a good idea having a lot of classes in a file ! Remember **Single Responsibility** is a good principle that will save you a  lot of time later!

Comment: @tereško you should follow teeyo's advice, your code would likely benefit following a nice conventional approach since you have chosen to use Laravel which is very opinionated and its major benefit is it focuses on the convention for file and class names over explicit configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the use of App\MyClass\SourceCredentials;

```
use App\MyClass\SourceCredentials;
```

Your controller should look like :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\MyClass\API;
use App\MyClass\SourceCredentials;
public function getservices(Request $request)
{
    $sourcename = request('sName');
    $password = request('password');
    $siteID = request('siteID');

   // initialize default credentials
    $creds = new SourceCredentials($sourcename, $password, 
    array($siteID));
```